# How can I limit the size of the MapReduceResults returned by Spring data Mongo's map reduce method

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

When using spring-data-mongodb's MongoTemplate to execute a map reduce operation, the method returns a MapReduceResults object.

In my use case this object (and its content) is not used (the results are merged with an existing collection on the database).

It appears that the MongoDB driver returns a cursor (no data) to the result, but that the spring libraries resolve this cursor to actual database objects.

This results in massive amounts of data being passed over the network and the calling job to fail because of an OutOfMemoryError.

Is there some way (without dropping down to the MongoDB driver directly) to limit the number of database objects returned by the Spring layer to the calling method?

- mongo-java-driver-2.12.1
- spring-data-mongodb-1.5.1.RELEASE

***UPDATE***:
It seems my assumption that this was a fairly generic question was incorrect.

Here is the code I am running. The 3 JS functions are stored in files and are loaded as strings by the loadFile() method.

I added the RHS of the results assignment here (its not in my code as I don't need/use the results). I'd love a version of the mapRecuce method that does NOT return anything.

```
 MapReduceOptions options = MapReduceOptions.options();

 options.outputTypeReduce();
 options.finalizeFunction(loadFile(finalizeFunctionFilename));
 options.outputCollection(output_collection_name);

List<DBObject> results = mongoTemplate.mapReduce(query,
    input_collection_name, 
    loadFile(mapFunctionFilename), 
    loadFile(reduceFunctionFilename), 
    options,
    DBObject.class);
```

Comment: No code here or an example of what you are doing. This is why it doesn't get much love. Show what you are doing if you expect an answer.

Comment: Is it not an option to limit the number of objects from the input collection?

Comment: Nope @PhillipGibb the limit option limits the size of the input, I definitely want the M/R to process the entire source collection. I just don't want it to return the entire output, putting the output int he output collection is all I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to drop down to the drivers.

This problem can be solved by extending the MongoTemplate class and overriding the mapReduce method.

Obviously care should be taken, when the libraries are upgraded, to port any changes to this new class.

The new method looks like this:

```
@Override
public <T> MapReduceResults<T> mapReduce(Query query, String inputCollectionName, String mapFunction,
        String reduceFunction, MapReduceOptions mapReduceOptions, Class<T> entityClass) {

    if (mapReduceOptions.getOutputType() == OutputType.INLINE) {
        // if output type is inline then no need to suppress results
        return super.mapReduce(query, inputCollectionName, mapFunction, reduceFunction, mapReduceOptions, entityClass);
    }

    String mapFunc = replaceWithResourceIfNecessary(mapFunction);
    String reduceFunc = replaceWithResourceIfNecessary(reduceFunction);

    DBCollection inputCollection = getCollection(inputCollectionName);

    MapReduceCommand command = new MapReduceCommand(inputCollection, mapFunc, reduceFunc,
            mapReduceOptions.getOutputCollection(), mapReduceOptions.getOutputType(), null);

    DBObject commandObject = copyQuery(query, copyMapReduceOptions(mapReduceOptions, command));

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Executing MapReduce on collection [{}], mapFunction [{}], reduceFunction [{}]",
                command.getInput(), mapFunc, reduceFunc);
    }

    CommandResult commandResult = executeCommand(commandObject);

    handleCommandError(commandResult, commandObject);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("MapReduce command result = [{}]", serializeToJsonSafely(commandObject));
    }

    return new MapReduceResults<>(new ArrayList<T>(), commandResult);
}
```

You will also need to port a few private methods across from the original MongoTemplate class so that this new class has access to them.